# How to add comments on multiline statements on Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am failing to add comments for multi-line statements in bash script. Seems that bash is not interpreting.

Since comments can really be useful because there are potential 4-5 lines, can anyone advice me how to achieve this?

This is just basic example, which is - not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -A INPUT \
#Comment for rule bellow
-p tcp --dport 21 \
# Comment for rule bellow no2
-s 10.0.0.1 \
-j ACCEPT
```

I just give a plain example. Allowing comments can be more easier for complex examples (*this is not complicated example, but you got a point*) like this:

```
grep some_file \
#awk does that...
awk '{print $1}' \
#sed does that...
sed 's/match1/match2/g'
```

Of course there are no whitechars behind `\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line broken into several lines by escaping the newline is still only one line.

A comment stretches from the `#` to the end of the line, no matter if that line is broken into many lines or not.

What the shell parses when you write

```
echo hello \
# world
```

is

```
echo hello # world
```

This is different though (and works):

```
grep hello |
# now sed:
sed 1p
```

Since each part of the pipeline is complete on its own line, it's possible to intermingle the lines with comments, *as long as* the newlines are *not* escaped.

Comment: Yes, true, forgot to include `|` in second example. Thank you for explanation!